# URL rewrite to another folder and file for specific requests

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have following directory structure on my local LAMP:

- `www`

  - basic

    - app

      - `router.php`
    - public

      - `index.html`
      - *.htaccess*

and I can access my index page with `localhost/basic/public/` and I am not using any virtual hosts.

Now I am trying to do two things:

1. Instead of `localhost/basic/public/` URL should look like
   `localhost/basic/` to access homepage.
2. All requests to `/api/` should be redirected to `router.php`. For
   example if I make a request like `/api/user/login` it should go to
   `app/router.php` where I can execute specific code according to
   request for API.

To achieve this I was trying do something like following in *.htaccess* file but its not working:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule . ../app/router.php [NC,L]
```

Also I am not sure if we can use relative paths in `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd move your *.htaccess* file to `/www/.htaccess`.  Apache only "executes" *.htaccess* files it finds along the path of the request.  Requests like `/api/`... will only "execute" an *.htaccess* in the docroot (`/www`) and will not "find" nor "execute" your *.htaccess* in `/www/basic/app/public/.htaccess`.

Having done that, for (1), do something like

```
RewriteRule ^basic/$ basic/public/ [NC,L]
```

For (2), do something like

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) basic/app/router.php?_REQUEST=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have some issue in Rest API, if i try -> abc.com/api/rest/products?limit=2 my site return 404 page error, how can i solve this and how can i get products using rest API.  @Sathiya Kumar